# Cannot Load m3u8: no EXTm3u delimiter JWPlayer Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, streaming, jwplayer

i can't speak english good sorry for this =) 
I have a web site for live stream. I use JWPlayer. 
Video runs smoothly on a computer (Chrome). 
But getting such an error in android devices.
[This is error's SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1UTM.png)

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
                   jwplayer('playerjxASSdasni').setup({
                       'id': 'playerID',
                       'width': '100%',
                       'height': '600',
                       'file': 'www.yyy.com:8080/live/asas.m3u8',
                       'androidhls': 'true',
                       'image': '/thumbs/bunny.jpg',
                       'modes': [
                              {type: 'html5',},
                              {type: 'flash', src: 'jwplayer/player.swf'},
                              {type: 'download'}
                                ]});
            </script>
```

It works fine on the computer
But why on android chrome also gives an error
I can't fix this.
And i find this [Ext Response Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOGPt.png) but i dont know what i can for fix this error.
Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. It was caused by wrong file extension.
This was my code:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("test-jwplayer-adaptive");
    playerInstance.setup({
        type: "hls",
        file: "http://example.com/adaptive-1.mp4", //A link to the HLS manifest
        mediaid: "xxxxYYYY" // MediaID generated by our platform in order to take advantage of our analytics
    });
```

The fix was changing .mp4 to .m3u8 file format.